# Cannot select by attribute for new attributes added by join in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: attribute-table, arcgis-pro, select-by-attribute

I'm new to ArcGIS Pro and am following some tutorials. I did a join to add some data to the attribute table of one of my layers. Now, when I go to select by attribute and look for those attributes they aren't there. You can see in the picture that the fields to the right of COMID are missing from the select by attributes pop-down window.

How do I get them to appear there?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some things to try are:

- Check whether you used the Join Fields tool to permanently join the tables or whether you just performed a temporary join on the table views which does not change their underlying data souces
- Go to the Catalog pane and Refresh the workspace containing that table
- Close the Geoprocessing pane, and then re-open it to see whether it re-reads the current state of the table